# Почему изменяется значение переменной?

Tags: c#

Дано

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 3; 
    int m = 8;

    if (n < 0 & ++m > 0) ; 
    Console.WriteLine(m);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Почему значение переменной m меняется на 9. Ведь оно в условие должно передаваться по значению?

Comment: if это не функция, что бы в неё что-то передавалось

Answer (score 12):

Дело в том, что оператор `&`, в отличие от оператора `&&`, не обладает short-circuiting-логикой. То есть он всегда вычисляет *оба* операнда.

Если бы вы написали

```
if (n < 0 && ++m > 0)
```

— второй операнд бы не вычислялся, т. к. значение первого уже определяет значение результата. Но с `&` у вас вычисляется и правая, и левая части, и переменная `m` увеличивается.

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/jlhqK9): код

```
int n = 3; 
int m = 8;

var b1 = n < 0 && ++m > 0; 
Console.WriteLine(m); // выводит 8

var b2 = n < 0 & ++m > 0; 
Console.WriteLine(m); // выводит 9
```

---

Цитата из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sbf85k1c.aspx):

> Оператор `&` вычисляет оба операнда независимо от значения первого из них.

---

Дополнение: поскольку `if (...)` не является вызовом подпрограммы, то он работает не с *копией*, а с *оригиналом* value type. Поэтому за блоком `if` изменения внутри блока всё ещё видны.

С другой стороны, даже если бы вместо `if` стоял вызов подпрограммы, вычисление фактических аргументов производится всё равно в контексте вызывающей функции, и изменения параметров видны. Не видны лишь изменения значений аргументов *внутри* вызываемой функции, т. к. туда уходят лишь копии параметров с типами-значениями.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю. Не понимаю того что если вэлью тайп передается по значению, то как могла измениться переменная вне блока IF. Она же должна быть вне области видимости.

Comment: @RVG никуда оно не передается, преинкремент прикладывается непосредственно к переменной `m`. Про "область видимости" - вообще непонятно.

Comment: @RVG: Дополнил ответ.